# Corregir este programa

Tags: c#

Buenas gente del foro:

Teniendo este programa, no se comporta como quiero. Se trata de usar solo las teclas flechas y la tecla Enter. Con ello se puede crear un nombre, escribir un nombre que quiera. Cuando ya termine, pulso Enter y se posiciona en la parte indicada en la imagen de abajo.

Aquí abajo, escribí todo a AAAAAAAAAAAAA.

Al pulsar Enter, tiene que ser capaz de señalar con las teclas flechas izquiera y derecha para poder elegir ATRÁS o GUARDAR.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Una vez que haya elegido con el símbolo en > ATRÁS, si pulsa Enter muestra un mensaje:

```
    Console.Write("HAS PULSADO ATRÁS   ");
```

El programa en esta parte se acaba ahí.

Si con las flechas del teclado selecciona en > GUARDAR, luego pulsa la tecla Enter. A parte que el nombre como en este caso AAAAAAAAAAA, se almacena en la variable...

```
    static string guardarNombre = "";
```

Muestra el mensaje: HAS GUARDADO y el nombre AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA en pantalla.

Código completo en C#:

```
using System;

namespace LCD_nombre_archivo_consola_06
{
    class Program
    {
        static string guardarNombre = "";
        static int coordenadaX = 0;
        static ConsoleKey key;

    static readonly char[] roALFANUMERICO = new char[] {
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'Ñ', 'O', 'P',
        'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h',
        'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'ñ', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'x', 'y',
        'z', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9','.', ',', '-', '_', ':', ';',
        '¿', '?', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}','=', '$','&', '"', ' '};

    static readonly int[] roINDICE_ARRAY = new int[] { 
        80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80 };

    private static readonly string[] roTEXTO = new string[] { "ATRÁS", "GUARDAR" };

    static int index = 0; 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Título de la pantalla.
        Console.Title = "Cambiar nombre";

        Inicio();
    }

    #region Inico.
    private static void Inicio()
    {
        // Tamaño de la ventana.
        Console.SetWindowSize(20, 5);

        // Fondo verde.
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;

        // Letras negras.
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

        // Limpiar pantalla.
        Console.Clear();

        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
        Console.Write("Nombre del relé 1:  ");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
        //Console.Write("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA");

        // Recorre todo el índice del array y el de los datos alfanumérico.
        for (int i = 0; i < roINDICE_ARRAY.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(roALFANUMERICO[roINDICE_ARRAY[i]]);
        }

        Console.SetCursorPosition(2, 3);
        Console.Write(roTEXTO[0]); // ATRÁS.
        Console.SetCursorPosition(12, 3);
        Console.Write(roTEXTO[1]); // GUARDAR.

        while (true)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(coordenadaX, 1);
            key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
            switch (key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                    if (coordenadaX < 15)
                        coordenadaX++;
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                    if (coordenadaX > 0)
                        coordenadaX--;
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                    roINDICE_ARRAY[coordenadaX]++;
                    if (roINDICE_ARRAY[coordenadaX] >= roALFANUMERICO.Length)
                    {
                        roINDICE_ARRAY[coordenadaX] = 0;
                    }
                    Console.Write(roALFANUMERICO[roINDICE_ARRAY[coordenadaX]]);
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                    roINDICE_ARRAY[coordenadaX]--;
                    if (roINDICE_ARRAY[coordenadaX] < 0)
                    {
                        roINDICE_ARRAY[coordenadaX] = roALFANUMERICO.Length - 1;
                    }
                    Console.Write(roALFANUMERICO[roINDICE_ARRAY[coordenadaX]]);
                    break;

                case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(1, 3);
                    Console.Write(">");

                    while (true)
                    {
                        key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

                        switch (key)
                        {
                            case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                            case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                                index = 1 - index;
                                break;

                            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                                Console.SetCursorPosition(coordenadaX, 1);
                                break;

                            case ConsoleKey.Enter:

                                break;
                        }

                        for (int a = 0; a < 2; a++)
                        {
                            Console.SetCursorPosition(1 + (10 * a), 3);
                            if (a == index)
                                Console.Write(">");
                            else
                                Console.Write(" ");
                        }

                        if (index == 0)  // se pulsó Atrás
                        {
                            Atras();
                            //break;  // vuelve a la edición de letras
                        }
                        
                        if (index == 1)  // se pulsó Guardar
                        {
                            Guardar();
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    private static void Atras()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
        Console.Write("HAS PULSADO ATRÁS   ");
        Console.ReadKey(); // Pulse cualquier tecla para salir.
    }

    private static void Guardar()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 1);
        Console.Write("HAS GUARDADO       ");
        for (int a = 0; a < roINDICE_ARRAY.Length; a++)
        {
            guardarNombre += roALFANUMERICO[roINDICE_ARRAY[a]].ToString();
        }
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 2);
        Console.Write(guardarNombre);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres que haga el programa? ¿Dónde está el fallo?